# how to represent OR function in prolog

Tags: prolog, logic, logical-operators

I just figured out how to run gprolog and the new problem of prolog confused me. The problem refers to binary search tree in prolog, assume

```
      8      
    /  \
   3   10  
  / \
 1   6
```

here has two types of facts that left(X,Y) when X is the left leaf of Y and right(X,Y) when X is the right leaf of Y,so I can say left(3,8) and left(1,3) and right(10,8) as my facts. Implement the rule above(X,Y) when X is above Y in terms of facts? So what I am thinking is X is above Y when Y is the left leaf of X OR Y is the right leaf of X.

I tried the rule

```
  above(X,Y) :- left(Y,X); right(Y,X).
```

When I run the query above(3,1) in gprolog. it asked me true? when I press enter and it returns yes and when I press ";" and it returns no because the system keep searching the second goal "right(1,3)".
I just wandering is there any possible it returns yes no matter I press enter or semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, (the relevant part of) your code is

```
left(1,3).
above(X,Y) :- left(Y,X); right(Y,X).
```

And your query is:

```
?-above(3,1).
```

The query returns true first because your goal is reached. Then it asks you if you want to look for **other results** (semicolon), you tell it to go ahead and look for **other ways** to prove your goal, and it answers that there was no other way (hence the "no").

Are you asking if there is a way to change the toplevel behavior of gprolog so that it answers "yes" to that second question?

It is, in theory, possible to reimplement your own Prolog compiler and make it output "yes" when it means to say "no", but why do such a thing? Other than that, no, you can't change that.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. The reason why I want to do that is make prolog more smart if it can recognize that there has truth in one of goals. Cause when I tried more further rule like anywayabove(X,Y): X is ancestor of Y, I still need to consider about keep searching or not question. It is kind of my computing, but not prolog computing. I was thought ";" in clause means it returns yes if one of goals matched no matter it keeps search or not. Does it make sense?

Comment: @user1234567 I don't think that would make prolog smarter. But have fun programming that new compiler!